# MongoDB Connection Refused, installation

Tags: mongodb, installation

I am new with mongoDB, I have just installed mongoDB following  [this doucumantation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)  and when i try to run using **mongo** i get the following error

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-03-02T17:59:27.311+0530 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-03-02T17:59:27.313+0530 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-03-02T17:59:27.313+0530 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

The status by running the command - **systemctl status mongod** is

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-03-02 17:32:55 IST; 30min ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
 Main PID: 16322 (code=exited, status=14)

Mar 02 17:32:55 hp-laptop-15-bs0xx systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Mar 02 17:32:55 hp-laptop-15-bs0xx systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exite
Mar 02 17:32:55 hp-laptop-15-bs0xx systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
lines 1-9/9 (END)
`
```

logs from /etc/mongod.conf is

```
# Where and how to store data. 
storage:   
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb   
  journal:
    enabled: true

# where to write logging data. 
systemLog:
  destination: file   
  logAppend: true   
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces 
net: 
  port: 27017 
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

# how the process runs 
processManagement:   
   timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
```

I also have started the database using `systemctl start mongod`

I also have uninstalled mongodb and reinstalled it again. I can't seem to figure out whats wrong.

Comment: Can you share the output of the logs. In ubuntu it is found at /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

Comment: i changed the user group permission for .SOCK in /tmp folder and the database starts when i run using mongo, however when i try to run using mongod, i have encountered an error :  ***aborting after fassert() failure.

Comment: there are no logs in /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log , i have updated my question with the logs from /etc/mongod.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your config file the `processManagement` section should be like this:

```
# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
```

Default for `processManagement.fork = false`, thus the service may not start.

Comment: I don't have enough badges to do it.